Ubuntu boot error, can’t load a lot of packages
I am a noob with Linux, but I already tried a few things like recovery mode. With dpkg repair it is repairing some packages, but that did not resolve it. Also the Boot-Repair tool did not help. I installed a second Ubuntu partition to find a solution and repair it, but none of my attempts were successful. My last attempt was to review the partitions and I think maybe I mixed something up with mounting, but when I check the specific partition it gives me the mounted status of /dev/sb6. I'd really like to repair it because I already did a lot of configuration stuff.

I already installed a new partition and I think I could backtrack my actions that ended in this corrupted version. It tried to get the ownership of one of the Mac Partitions that are in NTFS file format. Could this be the reason and can I reverse it?

It’s Ubuntu 24.04 LTS the NTFS-File system is the Mac OS Partition . I tried to overtake the ownership and did not recognise it was the Mac OS. Sorry for the wrong terms I meant with packets the not working files in the error picture.
